# Formulario con Java

Tags: javascript, html, formularios

En primer lugar, tengo un SELECT con dos valores, el valor A y el valor B. Y a  un DATE, y dos SELECT mas, uno para la hora y otro para los minutos

En el proyecto, tengo dos restaurantes, A y B. El restaurante B no abre los lunes, pero el restaurante A si abre los lunes, y cada uno tiene diferentes fechas de aperturas, el A esta abierto de 8:00 a 16:00, mientras que el B abre de 13:30 a 16:30

Cuando el valor B este seleccionado, en el DATE no se podrán seleccionar los lunes, pero si estuviese el valor A seleccionado en lugar del B, si se podría.

Posiblemente se ira complicando, y quizás un día habrán mas tarde, o cierren antes, de modo que en función del día de la semana elegido, aparezcan unas opciones para el SELECT de la hora y minuto.

Como puedo hacer una funcion. Que según el restaurante seleccionado (A,B) a su vez filtre el día seleccionado en el DATE (Lunes martes miércoles... [Si estuviese seleccionado el bar B no se podría elegir ningún lunes] ) y segun el restaurante elegido, y el día elegido, muestre una hora y minuto diferente seleccionable.

Espero haberme explicado bien, gracias por su atención. ^ ^

```css
select{
 width: 300px;
    padding: 12px 20px;
 margin: 4px 35px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    font-size: 16px;
    resize: none;
}
input[type=date]{
     padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 4px 35px;
 border: 2px solid #ccc;
 width: 300px ;
 font-size: 16px;
}
.horas{
width: 150px;
    margin-left: 35px;
  margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top:4px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}
.horass{
width: 300px;
margin: 4px 35px;
}
.horasss{
width: 150px;
margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 35px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}

label{
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size:17px;
  font-family:helvetica;
}
.tdxD{
 padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td class="tdxD"><label for="bar">Restaurante</label></td>
<td><select id="bar" name="restaurante"><option value="A">A</option><option value="B">B</option></select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tdxD"><label for="fname">Fecha de reserva</label></td>
<td><input type="date" name="fecha"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tdxD"><label for="fname">Hora de reserva</label></td>
<td><select name="hora" class="horas"><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="16">16</option><option value="17">17</option><option value="18">18</option><option value="19">19</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="21">21</option><option value="22">22</option><option value="23">23</option></select><select name="min" class="horasss"><option value="00">00</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="45">45</option></select></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el código que ya tienes?

Comment: Solo tengo HTML, pero vale, voy

Comment: ¿y la pregunta es?

Comment: Como hacerlo posible

Comment: Este sitio no es para preguntas del tipo "escribe-mi-codigo-por-mí", si no para las cuestiones específicas que te encuentres al escribir tu programa.

Comment: Stackoverflow no está diseñado para que la gente haga el trabajo de otra, debes aprender tu poco a poco.

Answer (score 1):

Tendrás que poner un poco de javascript en tu código. La mecánica sería la siguiente. Cada vez que la fecha cambia (o el resturante) validar el día de la semana para verificar si es correcto. Para ello tendrás que usar [`getDay`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp) sobre la fecha. Este método te devuelve el día de la semana y ya solo te queda mostrar un mensaje de error o hacer el tratamiento que necesites.

Con esto deberías poder resolver lo que preguntas.